# How to add specular lightning and reflected colors to object color in ray tracing?

Tags: java, graphics, render, raytracing, specular

I've been trying to code a very simple ray tracer in Java as a beginner learning experience. So far, I can render ambient and Lambertian shading and I've been trying to add specular highlights and reflections with no success.

Every website I've checked mentions the ambient + diffuse + specular equation but I don't understand how adding a certain specular value to R,G, and B for each pixels is suppose to add a white highlight.

I am also having trouble to figure out how to mix the reflected color and the object color with the shading.

[Here are the renders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6iEa.jpg)

Edit: After some tweaking, [here are the new results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaSFk.jpg)

My engine class code looks like this:

```
    Color color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
    Color reflected_color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
    Sphere obj = (Sphere) this.find_nearest_obj(ray, scene).get(0);
    Vector l = null;
    double obj_dist = (double) this.find_nearest_obj(ray, scene).get(1);

    if (obj == null)
      return color;

    for (Object o : scene.getObjects()) {
      if (o instanceof Vector) {
        l = (Vector) o;
      }
    }

    /*
     * Calculate specific fragment elements
     */

    Vector hit_pos = ray.getPoint().add(ray.getDir().mult(obj_dist));
    Vector normal = hit_pos.sub(obj.getCenter());
    Ray reflected_ray = get_reflected_ray(normal, ray, hit_pos, l);
    // Vector view = normal.mult(2).mult(-1 * normal.dot(ray.getDir()));
    Vector view = scene.getCamera().sub(hit_pos);

    if (obj.isReflective() && ctrl < 5) {
      ctrl++;
      reflected_color = ray_trace(reflected_ray, scene);
      // TODO: recursive reflection implementation
    }

    color = colorAt(obj, scene, normal, reflected_color, view, reflected_ray); // return fragment color

    return color;
  }

  public List<Object> find_nearest_obj(Ray ray, Scene scene) {
    double obj_dist = 0;
    Sphere obj_hit = null;
    List<Object> pair = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (Object s : scene.getObjects()) { // Find scene objects
      if (s instanceof Sphere) {
        double dist = ((Sphere) s).intersects(ray);
        if (dist > 0 && (obj_hit == null || dist < obj_dist)) {
          obj_dist = dist;
          obj_hit = (Sphere) s;
        }
      }
    }
    pair.add(obj_hit);
    pair.add(obj_dist);
    return pair;
  }

  public Ray get_reflected_ray(Vector normal, Ray ray, Vector hit_pos, Vector l) {
    return new Ray(new Point(hit_pos.x, hit_pos.y, hit_pos.z),
        ray.getDir().add(normal.mult(2).mult(-1 * normal.dot(ray.getDir()))));
//    return new Ray(new Point(hit_pos.x, hit_pos.y, hit_pos.z), l.sub(normal.mult(2).mult(normal.dot(l))));
  }

  public Color colorAt(Sphere obj, Scene scene, Vector normal, Color reflected_color, Vector view, Ray reflected) {
    Vector l = null;
    Vector frag_color = null;
    for (Object o : scene.getObjects()) {
      if (o instanceof Vector) {
        l = (Vector) o;
        if (l != null) {
          double diffuse = l.norm().dot(normal.norm());
          double specular = Math.pow(view.dot(reflected.getDir()), specular_coef);
          if (diffuse < 0)
            diffuse = 0;
          if (specular < 0)
            specular = 0;
            frag_color = (obj.getColor().add(reflected_color)).mult(ambient_control * ambient_coef + (1 - ambient_coef) * diffuse + specular);
        }
      }
    }
    return new Color(frag_color.x, frag_color.y, frag_color.z);
  }
}
```

Comment: The specular part is not just "*a certain specular value*". It is calculated for each pixel. And this calculation will produce zero contribution where there should be no highlight. Considering reflection should be a separate question after your local lighting is up and running. If you need help with the illumination calculation, please post the code for `colorAt`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I did some extra tweaking and I forgot to normalize some vectors for the reflected ray calculations. I added new images for the renders. The colorAt method body is included in the post.

Comment: It also seems that the specular highlights are present on both sides of the spheres (if you look at the reflection of the blue ball on the yellow ball for example).

Comment: Looks good in general. It is not a standard illumination model, but it can still make sense. `specular` should be set to 0 if `diffuse < 0` (the pow might make it positive). You usually just add the reflected light to the total light (multiplied by a reflectivity fraction).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I added the changes you suggested and it does look a lot better.